# 404 Error when page gets refreshed/revisited

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tried using **history mode** in vue.js to remove hash sign from the URL. Downside of this is when the page got refreshed / revisited, it occurs 404 Not Found. There's a documentation from the website about the History Mode and fixing it but I'm having trouble understanding it, sorry.

What I want is remove the history mode from the code, at the same time hash symbol gets removed from the url and 404 Error will be fixed.

I will provide the code below from the index.js that the web has. (*Note:* The website is already built this way and it was passed onto me since the developer that made this had problems.)

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const originalPush = VueRouter.prototype.push;
VueRouter.prototype.push = function push(location) {
  return originalPush.call(this, location).catch((err) => err);
};

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode:"history",
  routes,
});

const isLogin = true;
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  document.title = to.meta.title;
  if (to.name == "login" || isLogin) {
    next();
  } else {
    next("/login");
  }
});
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
  next();
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
});
export default router;
```

Do I need to do a new set of codes for me to able to do what I want? 404 Error fixed when page got refreshed / revisited, hash symbol gets removed from URL.

Comment: Can you provide more information?
1. Please show `routes` which you are passing to router. and route which you try to refresh/revisit.
2. Are you getting this error after deploying or at development time? Because in case of production, you might need to configure your web server. e.g. Nginx

Comment: @ChiragShah 1. the code that I find was this.$router.push ({ path: "/Tokenomics, }); and two more nav menus. 2. While in development I'm having the error right away when the page got revisited / refreshed. Even after deploying the files to the web server, error occurs. I also think it's the web server's fault. The server the site is using was Pagoda Linux Server, so I don't have any idea how to apply the code to the server. You can check the website here and try to refresh the nav menu after accessing it [Zoobit](http://zoobit.finance)

Comment: To use the history mode, you also need to configure the web server for it.

Comment: Check this link for web server setup - [https://megamorf.gitlab.io/2020/07/18/fix-404-error-when-opening-spa-urls/](https://megamorf.gitlab.io/2020/07/18/fix-404-error-when-opening-spa-urls/). For the development. Keep your `/` route at the end and all other route before that

Comment: Alright, will try to do this @ChiragShah. Thanks!

Comment: Let me know later on if my answer was helpful to you. :) Would love to help more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The default mode for Vue Router is hash mode. It uses a URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won’t be reloaded when the URL changes. Comment or remove mode: "history"

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  //mode:"history",
  routes,
});
```

See the example case here https://www.bezkoder.com/integrate-vue-spring-boot/

Comment: Yes. I can just remove the mode:"history" from the code. But it will bring back the hash sign from the URL, and remove the 404 error. But what they want is fix the 404 error when page gets refreshed, at the same time the hash from the URL is also removed.

Comment: Which Vue version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem some time ago, you just have to configure the vue router mode and install a package for the server, and configure the server as well. I leave the official guide [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode).

Vue router config:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',//Set the mode to 'history'
  routes: [...]
})
```

Server config (NOT express):

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const httpPort = 80

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('We cannot open "index.html" file.')
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    })

    res.end(content)
  })
}).listen(httpPort, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
})
```

For express node.js sever: For Node.js/Express, consider using [connect-history-api-fallback](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-history-api-fallback) middleware.